# Is it possible to load only specific components of magento?

Tags: api, magento-1, core

Does anyone know if it is possible to load specific components from the core of Magento. For example I am looking at building a custom XML-RPC for a remote system that interacts with Magento.

I have two options, I can build it into Magento and deal with the very slow times due to the level of abstraction and how Magento is built, or I can build a stand alone system that interacts directly with the database.

Both methods seem to be poor options. What I would like to know...  Is it possible to simply autoload only the components I need for my few calls. This way I can still leverage the Magento system via their own classes, but not have all the overhead and baggage that slows the system down.

Comment: What overhead did you determine to be present when dealing with the Magento API? It actually works the way you want, only classes are loaded that are needed. If you disagree with the choices of what will be needed, you can also extend the API and implement you shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

First about Magento components/overhead:
Magento will only load those components that are used in the executed code. Magento loads classes on the fly through an autoloader, so if a whole modules is not used, then no PHP code will be loaded, it does always load XML config files. Also Magento will always 'lazy load' everything (not process, run queries, render things, etc... until actually necessary).

I do agree that Magento out-of-the-box is not a very fast system. That is why you have a lot of possibilities to speed things up. If you enable all caches then loading config files will be fast because it will be cached. Also, in your case, accessing the API will be faster because Magento will cache the API config.
After that you can always turn to APC, Memcache, Redis etc... to get things even faster.

So my advice would be to try to speed things up at first. I would not suggest to write your own code/reuse Magento code in a separate application as this would need an extra application to maintain. What you could do is to duplicate your Magento installation, keep it running on the same DB, but turn off/strip off a lot of thing on this second setup.